# Reload object in an Entity Framework context with updated values

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an EF object that I pull from the db. I then make an update to the corresponding row in the DB through a function call which uses another `DBContext`. After this update, I would like to reload the contents of the object with the updated contents, however the EF context seems to cache the contents.
Here's a sample of the code(I've removed some unrelated fluff to make it simpler):

```
using (UmbrellaEntities context = new UmbrellaEntities())
{
    var umbrella = (from u in context.Umbrellas
                    where u.umbrellaId == umbrellaId
                    && !u.deleted
                    select u).Single();
    int oldVersion = umbrella.Version; 

    updateUmbrellaVersions(); //perform update on table Umbrella using a new `UmbrellaEntities` object.
    //ideally I'd like to be able to get the updated umbrella.Version without a new call.

    var umbrella = (from u in context.Umbrellas
                    where u.umbrellaId == umbrellaId
                    && !u.deleted
                    select u).Single(); 
     int newVersion = umbrella.Version; //at this point i expect newVersion to be different from oldVersion, since the value in the db has been updated, but that's not the case.
}
```

I find that I can use a new context to pull the updated context, but this is inefficient.

```
using (UmbrellaEntities context = new UmbrellaEntities())
{
        var umbrella = (from u in context.Umbrellas
                        where u.umbrellaId == umbrellaId
                        && !u.deleted
                        select u).Single();
        int oldVersion = umbrella.Version; 
        updateUmbrellaVersions(); //perform update on table Umbrella using a new `UmbrellaEntities` object.
}

using (UmbrellaEntities context = new UmbrellaEntities())
{
        var umbrella = (from u in context.Umbrellas
                        where u.umbrellaId == umbrellaId
                        && !u.deleted
                        select u).Single();
        int newVersion = umbrella.Version; //we have the right value
}
```

Is there a way to reload the contents directly after I perform the update?

Comment: why are you using a different dbcontext?

Comment: You mean why I'm using a new context inside the function `updateUmbrellaVersions` instead of moving the update code here or passing the dbContext to the update function? The update code calls a service whose API i cannot change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to call `context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,umbrella)` to make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: This seems to work, but it won't reload entity list properties as far as I can tell (e.g. foreign key data)