# Entity Framework - Navigation Property Not Eager/Lazy Loaded?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have the following entites:

```
public class Ticket 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RequestBy { get; set; }
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Requester { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Ticket as follows in my controller:

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    public BaseController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork; 
    }
}

public class TicketController : BaseController
{
    public TicketController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) { }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTicket(CreateTicketVM viewModel)
    {
         // repopulate dropdowns incase we need to return view
         // viewModel.Priorities is IEnumerable list
         viewModel.Priorities = UnitOfWork.PriorityRepository.GetPriorities();

        //validation code removed for brevity...

        var ticket = new Ticket
        {
           RequestBy = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.RequestBy) ? viewModel.RequestBy : User.Identity.GetUserId(),
           PriorityId = viewModel.PriorityId != 0 ? viewModel.PriorityId : (int)PriorityLevel.Medium,
        };

        UnitOfWork.TicketRepository.Add(ticket);
    }
}
```

Now when I debug `var ticket` after calling `.Add(ticket)` why has it loaded the related navigation property `Priority` and not the `Requester` navigation property despite the `RequestBy` value being set? As you can see I haven't defined any `virtual` keywords against either navigation properties?

Strangley this in only happening for all navigation properties that are of `ApplicationUser` type. All other navigation properties seem to get loaded even without using the `virtual` keyword???

Using fluent api I have defined the `RequestBy` FK as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
 .HasRequired(x => x.Requester)
 .WithMany()
 .HasForeignKey(x => x.RequestBy);
```

Below is additional code to provide some more context.

Ticket Repository:

```
public class TicketRepository : ITicketRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public TicketRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(Ticket ticket)
    {
        _context.Ticket.Add(ticket);
    }
}
```

Priority Repository:

```
public class PriorityRepository : IPriorityRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PriorityRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Priority> GetPriorities()
    {
        return _context.Priority.ToList();
    }
}
```

Unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ITicketRepository TicketRepository { get; private set; }
    public IPriorityRepository PriorityRepository { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        TicketRepository = new TicketRepository(_context);
        PriorityRepository = new PriorityRepository(_context);
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct either the classes listing or the question. `RequestBy` is a string in a model, so it doesn't have a `FirstName` property

Comment: @zaitsman sorry that was a typo

Comment: If you are using the same db context *instance* to retrieve data as you are to save the data then it is probably because you have set the Navigation property for *RequestBy* but not the one for *Priority* (only the ID). Easy test would be to set Priority and see what happens (or use a new context to retrieve data). Or you could ['force' a reload from the db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735291/entity-framework-4-1-how-to-force-ef-to-go-to-db-instead-of-using-graph) to test.

Comment: @Cal279 I have no idea what you are talking about. I'm using the same context and you can see from the posted code what navigation properties I have. If I debug `var ticket` after call to `_context.Ticket.Add(ticket);` I observe the above behaviour.

Comment: @adam78 what I am saying is that the data you set in RequestBy has 'effectively' been cached by the DBContext. If you use a new DBContext (i.e. create a new instance) when you get the data, you will see that neither of these Naviagation properies will be 'eagerly loaded'.

Comment: @Cal279 But I'm setting `RequestBy` and `PriorityId` at the same time?

Comment: Since `RequestBy` is not following the convention for explicit FK property name (which in this case is `RequesterId`), you need data annotations/fluent API to associate it with `Requester` navigation property. Currently EF is using shadow (hidden) property called `Requester_Id`.

Comment: @Cal279 that is correct `PriorityId` is not a navigation property but `Priority` is. When I call `ticket.Priority.Name` it works i.e it is lazy loaded. But `ticket.Requester.FirstName` is not loaded.

Comment: @IvanStoev please see my edit. I have defined the FK using fluent api but I'm still seeing the above behaviour

Comment: are you sure there is an ApplicationUser in the Database with the required PK?

Comment: Ok, now it's different. None of the two navigation properties should be loaded. If some is, then it's because the `_context` has been used for something else and the referenced entity has been tracked (loaded) in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither navigation property should be loaded. What you see is most likely a result of the so called navigation property fixup feature - if entity is already tracked by the context, EF updates navigation properties of the entities referencing it even if you don't specifically request that.

You can easily verify that by using `var _context = new YourDbContext();` local variable instead of the `_context` field. Or something like this:

```
var ticket = new Ticket
{
    RequestBy = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.RequestBy) ? viewModel.RequestBy : User.Identity.GetUserId(),
    PriorityId = viewModel.PriorityId != 0 ? viewModel.PriorityId : (int)PriorityLevel.Medium,
};

bool priorityLoaded = _context.Priority.Local.Any(e => e.Id == ticket.PriorityId);
bool userLoaded = _context.ApplicationUser.Local.Any(e => e.Id == ticket.RequestBy);

_context.Ticket.Add(ticket);
```

According to your description, `priorityLoaded` should be `true` while `userLoaded` - `false`.

Comment: I've updated my original post with some more code if that helps. I can't seem to figure out this behaviour. Please advise.

Comment: Your right. I just did a test by changing `public IEnumerable<Priority> GetPriorities()
        {
            return _context.Priority.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }` and it didn't get loaded.